# I am unable to understand the mustache JS used in the custom Marketing Cloud Preference Center Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, mustache.js

We are using a custom preference center page. I need to change the values at the front end but unable to understand the mustache written for this. The mustache is as below.

```
<section class="form-group card card-alternate">
        {{#Subscriptions}}{{#Options}}
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row" id="{{id}}Row">
                <div class="col-10">
                    <label>{{{***text***}}}</label>
                    <p>{{{description}}}</p>
                    {{#linkUrl}}<a href="{{linkUrl}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link active">View an example</a>{{/linkUrl}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 justify-content-center align-items-center d-flex">
                    <input class="tgl tgl-ios form-field" value="{{id}}" id="{{id}}" {{#OptInStatus}}checked{{/OptInStatus}} {{#IsDisabled}}disabled="true" {{/IsDisabled}} type="checkbox">
                    <label class="tgl-btn" for="{{id}}"></label>
                    <label class="tgl-btn-label" id="{{id}}Status">{{#IsDisabled}}Unavailable{{/IsDisabled}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/Options}}{{/Subscriptions}}
    </section>
```

Please help, what should be the possible source of this information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The information contained in the variables like text, description needs to be modified

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on GTL syntax:

> **Guide Template Language offers two types of user-defined data sources:**
>
> **Dataobjects** use a global scope, making data available for reuse
>   multiple times via section tags. **Datasources** reside locally within the
>   tags, making data accessible only inside the scope of the datasource
>   tags.

You can use a Data extension as well as a data source.

> Each attribute
>   of the data source, such as a **data extension** or a **user-defined data**
>   **source**, is available using the name of the attribute.

I think your data sources are somewhere before the code you've shared here OR a DE is used as Data source and the tags represents your DE's fields..

There are different types of tags used in your code:

**Simple tag:**

> Use simple tags to display content from data sources.

Example from your code:

```
{{linkUrl}}
```

**Sections:**

> Sections use block tags and a # prefix. Use sections to render content
>   based on the values contained in the data reference.

Example from your code:

```
{{#Subscriptions}}{{#Options}}...{{/Options}}{{/Subscriptions}}
```

**References:**

- [**GTL syntax guide**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/gtlSyntaxGuide.htm)
- [**GTL Sections**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/gtlSections.htm)
- [**GTL Data Sources**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/gtlUserDefinedDataSources.htm)